# How to read One Ring inscription?

Tags: tolkien-black-speech, tengwar

The following [inscription appears on the One Ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Ring#Inscription) in *The Fellowship of the Ring* book:

[image: Ash nazg durbatulûk, ash nazg gimbatul, Ash nazg thrakatulûk agh burzum-ishi krimpatul. One ring to rule them all, one ring to find them, One ring to bring them all and in the darkness bind them.]

Which in Black Speech can be written down as:

> Ash nazg durbatulûk, ash nazg gimbatul,
>
> Ash nazg thrakatulûk agh burzum-ishi krimpatul.

However, the inscription is using different letters. I've checked [Tengwar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tengwar), but I can't find any of the words (e.g. *ash*, *nazg*, etc.).

How should the inscription be read exactly, in other words, how it's transformed from the above fiery letters into latin letters?

Comment: There's an article on [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Speech) with list of known words. (The ring inscription section). Unless you mean the pronouncation

Comment: Letter by letter transliteration is possible using resources such as [this](https://waymoot.org/home/tengwar/teng.html), I'd done something similar for my answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/179012/68872) on SFF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are likely having a hard time reading these tengwar because of [three big problems](http://at.mansbjorkman.net/teng_general_black_speech.htm):

1. the style itself is such that the tengwar are [slanted and written 
   calligraphically](http://at.mansbjorkman.net/teng_calligraphy.htm#ring)
2. the mode used to write them is [unusual and not common](http://at.mansbjorkman.net/teng_general_black_speech.htm#vowels) for Elvish languages
3. there are no spaces between words!

The page linked should provide assistance; the issue is that the tengwar and tehtar behave (like in several modes) as in an abugida: the vowels are diacritics to the "host" consonants, and a null consonant is used for vowel-initial words (even when the words aren't separated by spaces).

Comment: (2) In particular, no attested Elvish language has /ʃ/ as in _ash_. But the title pages use tengwar and cirth for English; if you decipher those, you can confirm that (as mentioned in the Appendix) the columns of tengwar that represent _t, p, k, kw_ and their kin in Elvish are used in English and Black Speech for _t, p, č, k_ and their kin, respectively.  Thus _ash_ is written with the tengwa that in Elvish would stand for /kh/, while _nazg_ and _–uk_ use the tengwar for /gw/ and /kw/.